# How to correctly return nested types in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to return empty lists if one of the parameters is Nothing, but I can't

```
data UtilsDiff = UtilsDiff {syntaxBlockOptions :: [String], optionsBlockOptions :: [String]}
  deriving Show
  
data UtilsOrDiff = UtilsOrDiff Utils | Diff UtilsDiff
  deriving Show

useBlockExpr :: Parser UtilsOrDiff
useBlockExpr = do
  u1 <- syntaxExpr
  opts <- optionsBlockExpr
  _ <- absorbToStopWord "Description:"
  utilDesc <- many anyChar
  case options u1 of
    Nothing -> Diff [] [] -- <- this line
    Just val-> do
      ...
```

Apparently I haven't figured out exactly how to return the Diff type

```
warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]     
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0] -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT String () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity UtilsOrDiff’ with actual type ‘UtilsOrDiff’
 • The function ‘Diff’ is applied to two value arguments,but its type ‘UtilsDiff -> UtilsOrDiff’ has only one 
In the expression: Diff [] [] In a case alternative: Nothing -> Diff [] []
```

Comment: `Diff` is not a type; it's a data constructor of the `UtilsOrDiff` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Diff` has type `UtilsDiff -> UtilsOrDiff`, not `[a] -> [a] -> UtilsDiff`. You need to create the `UtilsDiff` value first, then use *that* to create the `Diff` value.

```
Nothing -> return $ Diff (UtilsDiff [] [])
```

As the `Just` branch presumably evaluates to a `Parser UtilsOrDiff` value, so must the `Nothing` branch, hence the call to `return`.

Comment: It's strange, I think I tried to do something similar. Thanks for the help!